# Fetch data from select-options field in Angular

Tags: angularjs

In my HTML code I have a select-options field with ng-model. Want to register it's value in my controller and see every time when it will be changed. However console.log() displays it as undefined. I tried $scope.$watch but it didn't work as well. How can I solve that problem?

```
<select ng-model="selectedAge">
   <option value="none">None</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you please show controller code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your requirement using watch is the solution. write watch like this

```
$scope.$watch('selectedAge', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal)
})
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.obj = {};
  $scope.obj.showSelect = true
 $scope.$watch('obj.selectedAge',function(newVal, oldVal){
    console.log(newVal)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

<div ng-if="obj.showSelect">
  <select ng-model="obj.selectedAge">
   <option value="none">None</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select> 
</div></div>
```

**EDITED**

You must create empty object inside controller like this.

```
 angular.module("app", [])
    .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.obj = {};
        $scope.obj.showSelect = true
        $scope.$watch('obj.selectedAge', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log(newVal)
        })
    })
```

Check the updated demo above.

The reason is ng-if directive, like other directives creates a child scope. so you need to create a object and assign value trough that object.

**PS**
try to use ng-change instead of $scope.$watch(); because $watch is a bad practice for angular app performance.

Comment: Hey yes it works. Now I see where the problem was. I've puted that field into ng-if brackets so even when it appeared controller didn't notice any differences. Do you know how can I use this select-option within ng-if section?

Comment: i did't fully understand what you said. can u add some code and explain again

Comment: My select field is inside <div ng-if> </div> tag and this is the reason why it didn't work. When I remove div everything works. So it looks like this: 

<div ng-if="true">
<select ng-model="selectedAge">
some options
</select>
</div>

How can I make it work within this div ng-if tag?

Comment: Yes it's important since content of that tag should appear only when the user would choose it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use $watch as $watch create performance issue.Simply Use ng-change

```
 <select ng-model="selectedAge" ng-change="selectAge()">
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/t8t3n7ec/)